interface prop value - allow value similar to Array.join() but from keyof
I have an interfaces:
interface A {
  foo: string;
  bar: string;
  baz: string;
}

and:
interface B {
  field: keyof A;
}

Which lets me do something like:
const b: B = {
  field: 'foo'
}

I was wondering if there's any way to be able to change the type of field in interface B to be able to set values that is a combination of any two keys joined with a dot, so something like:
const c: B = {
  field: 'foo.bar'
}

Have been trying for a while but I can't come up with a valid solution. Thanks in advance.

You can use a template literal type

Template literal types build on string literal types, and have the ability to expand into many strings via unions.
They have the same syntax as template literal strings in JavaScript, but are used in type positions. When used with concrete literal types, a template literal produces a new string literal type by concatenating the contents.
[...]
When a union is used in the interpolated position, the type is the set of every possible string literal that could be represented by each union member
[...]
For each interpolated position in the template literal, the unions are cross multiplied

interface A {
  foo: string;
  bar: string;
  baz: string;
}

interface B {
  field: `${keyof A}.${keyof A}`;
}

const c: B = {
  field: 'foo.bar'
}

Playground Link

oh nice! can you use template literal to join any number of keys? so 'foo.bar' but also 'foo.bar.baz' ? to basically have any number of keys joined with dot as value

i guess not indefinitely, because it actually expands out in the compiler.
